# Android Studio + Flutter missing tools.jar file

Tags: java, flutter, android-studio, gradle

On Windows, i work with Flutter using Android Studio.

Since i was facing some issues before this one, i have successfully uninstalled and reinstalled the latest versions of both Android Studio and Java.

So, on this machine, i have:

- Android Studio `Electric Eel 2022.1.1.19`
- jdk 19 `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19`
- jre 1.8 `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_361`

Since Android Studio uses its own jre, i have copy-pasted the content of jdk folder into `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre`

Environment variables are properly set: JAVA_HOME leads to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19` and Path contains both `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19\bin` and `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_361\bin`

This is the problem i'm facing now if i try to build my flutter project:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':device_info_plus:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not find tools.jar. Please check that C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre contains a valid JDK installation.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 13s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Now, the main problem is that the file `tools.jar` DOES NOT EXIST AT ALL.
Is there a way to fix this?

Side Notes:

- flutter doctor -v

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.10, on Microsoft Windows [Versione 10.0.19045.2486], locale it-IT)
    • Flutter version 3.3.10 on channel stable at C:\Users\~\sdks\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 135454af32 (5 weeks ago), 2022-12-15 07:36:55 -0800                       
    • Engine revision 3316dd8728                                                                   
    • Dart version 2.18.6                                                                          
    • DevTools version 2.15.0                                                                      
                                                                                                   
Checking Android licenses is taking an unexpectedly long time...[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\~\AppData\Local\Android\sdk                                                                            
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 31.0.0                                                                                                   
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java                                                                      
    • Java version Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_361-b09)                                                                        
    • All Android licenses accepted.                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                
[√] Chrome - develop for the web                                                                                                                
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                
[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Professional 2022 17.4.4)                                                                
    • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional                                                               
    • Visual Studio Professional 2022 version 17.4.33213.308                                                                                    
    • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.22000.0                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                                
[√] Android Studio (version 2022.1)                                                                                                             
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio                                                   
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:                                                                       
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter                                                          
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:                                                                          
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart                                                             
    • Java version Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_361-b09)                                          
                                                                                                                  
[√] VS Code (version 1.74.3)                                                                                      
    • VS Code at C:\Users\~\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code                                   
    • Flutter extension version 3.56.0                                                                            
                                                                                                                  
[√] Connected device (4 available)                                                                                
    • sdk gphone64 x86 64 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x64    • Android 12 (API 31) (emulator)              
    • Windows (desktop)            • windows       • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Versione 10.0.19045.2486]
    • Chrome (web)                 • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 108.0.5359.125                
    • Edge (web)                   • edge          • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 109.0.1518.55                
                                                                                                                  
[√] HTTP Host Availability                                                                                        
    • All required HTTP hosts are available                                                                       
                                                                                                                  
• No issues found!
```

- Android Studio builds and launches native Android apps without any issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually i found the solution: here it is, hoping to help someone in the future.

Note: I had to download the jdk-17 because as of today jdk-19 would not work with flutter.

You need to add the path to find your java jdk into your `projectfolder/android/gradle.properties` file.
simply add this line
`org.gradle.java.home=C\:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-17`

here's my gradle.properties file to give an example

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
android.bundle.enableUncompressedNativeLibs=false
org.gradle.java.home=C\:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-17
```

If you installed jdk into another path, you need to specify that in here